# Sum of Jacobi symbol numerators

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, jacobi-symbol

According to Theorem 2 of [K. Ono, S. Robins, and P. T. Wahl, On the representation of integers
as sums of triangular numbers, Aequationes Math. 50 (1995), 73–94.](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/publications-cv/pdfs/006.pdf), define with $\left( \frac{r}{n} \right)$ being the Jacobi symbol,
$$R_3(n) = 
\begin{cases}
24 \sum_{r=1}^{\lfloor n/4 \rfloor} \left( \frac{r}{n} \right), & \text{if}\ n \equiv 1 \mod 4  \\
8 \sum_{r=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \left( \frac{r}{n} \right), & \text{if}\ n \equiv 3 \mod 4 \\
\end{cases}
$$

The number of ways to represent $n$ as the sum of $3$ squares is 
$$r_3(n) = \sum_{d^2 \mid n} R_3 \left( \frac{n}{d^2} \right)$$

My question is how to efficiently compute the sum of Jacobi symbols for a fixed denominator and range of numerators, if possible.

It's well known the Jacobi symbol is completely multiplicative:
$$\left( \frac {ab} n \right) = \left( \frac a n \right) \left( \frac b n \right)$$ 
So perhaps it's possible to use a sieve to calculate all values in range based on their prime factors, though the time complexity is close to linear. A sublinear algorithm would be ideal (I'm fairly certain I can take the algorithmic DP approach for the original problem).

Comment: is there a reason why are you including $r_3$ and $R_3$ in your question ?

Comment: @mercio to give context of the problem